# Count non-NA values by each column in dplyr using summarize_if

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to count the number of non-missing rows in each column that meets a criteria. Below is the code I currently have.

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  summarize_if(is.numeric, sum(!is.na()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that [`summarise_if`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) has been superseded, so it's recommended to use `across` and `where` instead. However, your original code was close, you just needed a tilde (`~`).

The dataset `mtcars` has no missing values, so I used `airquality` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(airquality)

airquality %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(!is.na(.x))))
#>   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#> 1   116     146  153  153   153 153

airquality %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, ~ sum(!is.na(.x)))
#>   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#> 1   116     146  153  153   153 153
```